# Why is my MSE so high when the difference between test and prediction values are so close?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In Python, I have conducted a small multiple linear regression model to explain house prices in areas based on other variables (all of which are percentages multiplied by 100) such as percentage of people with bachelor degrees in an area, percentage of people who work from home. I have conducted this in R and it works fine, but I am new to Python ML. I have shown the output of `y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)` and the MSE I get. I have included a sample of my data where `avgincome` `PctSingleDetached` and `PctDrivetoWork` are X, and `AvgHousingPrice` is the Y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

sample data:

      avgincome     PctSingleDetached   PctDrivetoWork    AvgHousingPrice 
0      44388.0          61.528497       81.151832          448954   
1      40650.0          54.372197       77.882798          349758  
2      43350.0          68.393782       79.553265          428740

X = hamiltondata.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = hamiltondata.iloc[:, -1].values
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean') # This is an object of the imputer class. It will help us find that average to infer. 
                         # Instructs to find missing and replace it with mean

# Fit method in SimpleImputer will connect imputer to our matrix of features                       
imputer.fit(X[:,:]) # We exclude column "O" AKA Country because they are strings
X[:, :] = imputer.transform(X[:,:])

# from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
# from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
# ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder = 'passthrough')
# X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))

print(X)
print(Y)


## Splitting into training and testing ##
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

### Feature Scaling ###

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler() # this does STANDARDIZATION for you. See data standardization formula
X_train[:, 0:] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[:,0:])
# Fit changes the data, Transform applies it! Here we have a method that does both

X_test[:, 0:] = sc.transform(X_test[:, 0:]) 

print(X_train)
print(X_test)

## Training ## 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

regressor = LinearRegression() # This class takes care of selecting the best variables. Very convenient
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)

### Predicting Test Set results ###

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
np.set_printoptions(precision = 2) # Display any numerical value with only 2 numebrs after decimal
print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), Y_test.reshape(len(Y_test),1 )), axis=1)) # this just simply makes everything vertical

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 
mse = mean_squared_error(Y_test, y_pred)
print(mse)

OUTPUT: 
[[489066.76 300334.  ]
 [227458.2  200352.  ]
 [928249.59 946729.  ]
 [339032.27 350116.  ]
 [689668.21 600322.  ]
 [489179.58 577936.  ]]
...
...


MSE = 2375985640.8102403
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate mse yourself to check if there is something wrong. In my opinion the obtained result is coherent. Anyway I built a simple my_mse function to check the result output by sklearn, with your example data

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error 

list_ = [[489066.76, 300334.], 
[227458.2,  200352.  ],
[928249.59, 946729.  ],
[339032.27, 350116.  ],
[689668.21, 600322.  ],
[489179.58, 577936.  ]]

y_true = [y[0] for y in list_]
y_pred = [y[1] for y in list_]

mse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
print(mse)
# 8779930962.14985

def my_mse(y_true, y_pred):
  diff = 0
  for couple in zip(y_true, y_pred):
    diff+=pow(couple[0]-couple[1], 2)
  return diff/len(y_true)

print(my_mse(y_true, y_pred))
# 8779930962.14985
```

Remember the mse is the mean **squared** error. (Each error is squared in the sum)

If you are asking if your model is bad or good, it depends on the main objective. Anyway, I think that your model is performing poor because it's a linear model. A model with more complexity could handle the problem and output better results